# Problem with static transform publisher

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-kinetic, freenect-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i have a Microsoft Kinect sensor and i am using the freenect  driver to use it, Then I transform my pointcloud to a laserscan and show it on my base_link frame. I get the following error:

Transform failure: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1594648338.669846591 but the earliest data is at time 1594648338.900337345, when looking up transform from frame [kinect_depth_optical_frame] to frame [base_link]

[image: image description]

On the Image you can see the current Transformation tree. When you need some information than please tell me.

Regards,
markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357030/problem-with-static-transform-publisher/) by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at your `rqt_tf_tree`, I assume the `/base2kinect` node that is publishing the transform is a `static_transform_publisher` from the tf library:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher

This uses the tf1 library, which requires you to put a publishing period and uses the `/tf` topic. Instead, use the tf2 version of the static transform publisher:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros#static_transform_publisher

This works the same as the tf1 version, but doesn't take a publishing period as the final argument, as it uses the new `/tf_static` topic which is used for fixed frame transformations. Replacing your tf1 static publisher with this tf2 static publisher should solve your time extrapolation error.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could add the transform from `base_link` to `kinect_link` as a fixed joint in your URDF file.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2020-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-07-13**:
Is tf2 a ROS2 package, or/and what are the benefits of using it with ROS1?

**Comment by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on 2020-07-13**:
thank you it works!

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2020-07-13**:
`tf2` is a major improvement and feature enhancement to `tf` that has been around since ROS Hydro. The `tf2` migration guide has the details: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration. The `/tf_static` topic is one of the new features, which avoids these timing issues with fixed transforms. In the `rqt_tf_tree`, when you see a publish rate of 10000 Hz, this means it is a static transform published on `/tf_static`.